# Generating non-duplicate numbers using Arrays, not ArrayList<> in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm doing the old *Lotto* exercise and I need to specifically use an **Array[]** of integers and not an **ArrayList**. I have what I thought would work, but I seem to be wrong. I looked for posts similar to these and all of them involved an **ArrayList<>**. Here is a partition of my code.

```
Integer[] lottoNums;
lottoNums = new Integer[7];

for(int i = 0; i < lottoNums.length; i++){

    lottoNums[i] = randomNums.nextInt((59)+1);

    
    if(i <= 5) {
        if(lottoNums[i].equals(lottoNums[i+1])){
            if(lottoNums[i] < 58 && lottoNums[i] > 1)
                lottoNums[i] = lottoNums[i] +1;
        }
    }
    else if(i >= 1) {
        if(lottoNums[i].equals(lottoNums[i-1])){
            if(lottoNums[i] < 58 && lottoNums[i] > 1)
                lottoNums[i] = lottoNums[i] +1;
        }
    }
}
    
Arrays.sort(lottoNums);
System.out.print("Winning numbers: "+lottoNums[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) { 
     System.out.print(", " + lottoNums[i]);
}
System.out.print(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
System.out.println("Bonus Number: "+lottoNums[6]);
```

I need to get it to generate a number in between `1` and `59` and not duplicate. I was trying to pair it up with the value stored in the element before and after it (if it had one) and if it was equal to it, it would add 1 to it. I run it a few times and every once in a while im still getting duplicate numbers. How can i do this efficiently, using **Arrays[] of integers ONLY?**

EDIT:

Initialized array to remove NullPointerException.

## Updated Code:

---

---

```
for(int i = 0; i < lottoNums.length; i++){
    
        lottoNums[i] = randomNums.nextInt((59)+1);
    
    }
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
           int rnd = randomNums.nextInt((lottoNums).length-i);
           int k = lottoNums[lottoNums.length-i-1];
           lottoNums[lottoNums.length-i-1] = lottoNums[rnd];
           lottoNums[rnd] = k;
        }
        
    Arrays.sort(lottoNums);
    System.out.print("Winning numbers: "+lottoNums[0]);
    //PRINTING LOTTO NUMBERS
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) { 
         System.out.print(", " + lottoNums[i]);
    }
        System.out.print(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        System.out.println("Bonus Number: "+lottoNums[6]);
```

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to put numbers 1 through 59 into an array (of length 59), shuffle it using `Arrays.shuffle`, and then take items sequentially from the array.

Comment: Arrays.shuffle()?   There's no Arrays.shuffle().

Comment: (There's a Collections.shuffle(), but that uses List type which OP didn't want to...)

Comment: Right you are! Bad me for SO'ing before bed.  `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(yourArray))` will do the trick.

Comment: I have to specifically not use arrays as lists

Comment: @BadZen Recieving a NullPointerException Error. Look above for code.

Comment: You need to initialize your lottoNums array.   You're using an array of all nulls, and it's trying to unbox a null to an int value.   

Something like for (int i = 0; i < lottoNums.length; i++) lottoNums[i] = i;

Or whatever the correct lotto number range is...  sorry, should have mentioned that part.   My code only /permutes/ the original array.

Comment: @BadZen I initialized and got rid of the exception, although, it is still duplicating numbers, the code is once again updated in the original post

Comment: You need to use the last six numbers in the array as I indicate - you are using the first six instead.  There shouldn't be dups tho.

Comment: @BadZen Im not sure what you mean, in my eyes i only have one set of 7 integers. Where do my first and last six come in and what line of that code differentiates which set i'm using? i apologize for the redundancy.

Comment: Change lottoNums to int[MAX_LOTTO_NUMBER+1], and maybe not +1 depending on how you deal with zeros?   you want all of the numbers from 1 to max number in there.  Then shuffle with my simple algo.   Then take the last 7 to return.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by switching the selected number with the last number in the array each time, and then selecting the next from the prefix you have not yet stored:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   int rnd = randomNums.nextInt(numbers.length-i);
   int k = numbers[numbers.length-i-1];
   numbers[numbers.length-i-1] = numbers[rnd];
   numbers[rnd] = k;
}
```

At the end of this loop your selected numbers will be in numbers[numbers.length-7..numbers.length-1], etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two arrays.  Each time you draw a number see if it exists in the second array.  If not use it and add it to the second array.